# Enable word wrap automatically on labels

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, autolayout, nstextfield

In iOS, you can have a `UILabel` and set its `numberOfLines` property to zero and it will automatically word wrap to fit content. Is there any way to do this in OS X using Cocoa? OS X uses `NSTextField` for labels, and there is no equivalent property or method there. Is it possible to do this in OS X?

Note: I'm using auto layout, so it would be great if there is a solution to works with it so the other, nearby views can be resized as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Multiline Label for this purpose. Find this control (another NSTextField) in the Object Library. Or select common Label control and change its `Layout` property to `Wraps`-value.

Comment: Okay, I'll look into it, but I don't think it will be suitable for my purposes.